# how do I convert a list of custom type to a list of String

Tags: haskell

I have a custom data given below:

```
data Item = Item {
    name:: String,
    identifier:: String,
    itemAction:: Action
    }
```

I want to convert a list of  this data type `[Item]` into another list that has only the Item's name `[Item.name]`which is `[String]`

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this question does not get closed, for future readers, this is a typical case for the "fmap" function, which is part of [functor class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html), and historically referred to as "map".

fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

Intuitively, what fmap does is that is apply a function inside a container. This container can be a List, and in this case fmap definition will build the list composed by applying function to each element.